# How to POST JSON HTTP Request to RESTful API made by WCF

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest, request

I am trying to make Android consume a simple WCF webservice made by my self. Here is my WCF Service definition:

```
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    UriTemplate = "/UploadCallLog2")]
    [OperationContract]
    String UploadCallLog2(String number, String cached_name, String duration, String date, String line_number);
```

I have two questions:
1. And what should my HTTP Request Look Like? What kind of Content type should I choose when add the request header?
2. Is there the correct way to put input param in body as JSON and the webservice can auto detect the value of input parameters?

Fred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using an MVC project for this over a WCF service.

The controller can return a JsonResult, the MVC library contains Json helper methods to serialize and deserialize the json objects into c# objects if the properties match.

Also this then allows the MVC based service to be called from any client that has support for XmlHttpRequest using ContentType as "application/json".  You can use either HttpGet or HttpPost depending on your request type and security of data under SSL as well.  You can also take advantage of the authentication model to secure your methods.

This just makes for a really clean implementation that doesn't have any complex server and client configurations.  More information regarding similar approaches is the new Web API in MVC 4.